# How to add a cms static block to all pages in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.4, magento-1.5, magento

I am new to magento and i am trying to create a static block for my home, category and other pages. i want the static block to be shown just above the footer link. And is there any good tutorial on line which can provide a good over view of static blocks. How to use them in CMS and how we can generate them using php Code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding Static and non-static blocks directly to templates:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()
->createBlock('cms/block')
->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Short code inside another block or cms page :

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id"}}
```

[For Reference Visit Here](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/magento/magento-static-blocks/)

Comment: http://myphpinformation.blogspot.in/2015/01/how-to-create-magento-static-block.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_id')->toHtml(); 
    // toy can use this code in your template file.    
?>
```

used in your cms pages like a short code

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id"}} 
// used in your cms pages like a short code
```

Answer (score 0):

To display Static block in .phtml files :

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('static_block_id')-toHtml(); 
?>
```

To display Static block in CMS pages :

```
{{block type="cms/block" block_id="my_block" template="cms/content.phtml"}}
```